# dockerfile with django in visual studio code won't launch due to path not found

Tags: python, django, docker, visual-studio

I am following a tutorial from visual studio code on creating a docker web app to run my python script in.
for your information it is visible in the following link:
https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/containers/quickstart-python
I followed the django tutorial before this on installing it correctly and tested it so that it works. After allowing vs code to create all my necessary files, i tried to run it via my launch.json file.

```
    {
    // Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
    // Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
    // For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Python: Django",
            "type": "python",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "${workspaceFolder}\\manage.py",
            "args": [
                "runserver"
            ],
            "django": true,
            "justMyCode": true
        },
        {
            "name": "Docker: Python - Django",
            "type": "docker",
            "request": "launch",
            "preLaunchTask": "docker-run: debug",
            "python": {
                "pathMappings": [
                    {
                        "localRoot": "${workspaceFolder}",
                        "remoteRoot": "/app"
                    }
                ],
                "projectType": "django"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

when i try this, i instantly get returned:

```
> docker build --rm --pull -f "H:\Dockerfile" --label "com.microsoft.created-by=visual-studio-code" -t "h:latest" "H:\" <
unable to prepare context: path "H:\"" not found
The terminal process failed to launch (exit code: 1).
```

I installed everything on my H drive, and after this error I added the H to my PATH by adding H:\ to it. But unfortunately the error persists.
does anyone have a clue on how I could solve this?

Comment: since the build context is H: as mentioned by the last argument of your build command. You must specify path for Dockerfile relative to the build-context. So in your case it should be `-f "Dockerfile" ` as it on the root of build context.

Comment: thanks for your response. 
I tried adding the -f "Dockerfile" to the command, but then the response is "failed to solve with frontend dockerfile.v0: failed to read dockerfile: open /var/lib/docker/tmp/buildkit-mount505732702/dockerfile: no such file or directory"
The Dockerfile is located on the H:\ drive as well

Comment: One thing I notice is that there is an extra ending quote in the error message `unable to prepare context: path "H:\""`. I don't know if that's related to your error or where it comes from.

Comment: @DennisHeemskerk : If you look at error message it says : dockerfile in smallcase whereas expected name is Dockerfile (default-name) or you can simply remove that -f flag (in case Dockerfile is present at root in build context)

Comment: yes the Dockerfile is in the root. but i think that that was the problem actually. i started again but not from the root and i resolved this specific error. unto the next one. Still thanks for responding!